# Single click listener for two in android

Tags: android, onclick

In the following code i am creating a click listener separately for two tables. How to make a single click event for both to compare their row id's. Because after comparing rows i have to draw a line between them.

```
for (i = 0; i < data.getItem().size(); i++) {

        final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        final TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
              new TableLayout.LayoutParams
              (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        int leftMargin=0;
        int topMargin=2;
        int rightMargin=0;
        int bottomMargin=1;

        tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

        tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
        tr1.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

        match1[i]= new TextView(this);
        match1[i].setId(i);
        System.out.println(match1[i].getId());
        match1[i].setText(data.getItem().get(i));
        System.out.println(match1[i].getText().toString());
        match1[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        match1[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        match1[i].setTextSize(12);
        match1[i].setPadding(10,0,0,0);
        tr.addView(match1[i]);
        Log.e("TAG", "ID: "+match1[i].getId());
        final View row=t1.getChildAt(i);
        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v){
            int row_id=t1.indexOfChild(row);
            Log.e("TAG ID for Table 1", "ID: "+row_id);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), row_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        });
        t1.addView(tr, tableRowParams);

        match2[i]= new TextView(this);
        match2[i].setId(i);
        match2[i].setText(data.getTarget().get(i));
        System.out.println(match2[i].getText().toString());
        match2[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        match2[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        match2[i].setTextSize(12);
        //match2[i].setPadding(10,0,0,0);
        tr.addView(match2[i]);
        Log.e("TAG ID For Tabel 2", "ID: "+match1[i].getId());
        final View row1=t2.getChildAt(i);
        row1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v){
            int row_id=t2.indexOfChild(row1);
            Log.e("TAG", "ID: "+row_id);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), row_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        });
        t2.addView(tr1, tableRowParams);

        /*if(match1[i].getId() == match2[i].getId()){
            //draw.onDraw(canvas);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Yipee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
            Toast.makeText(this, ":(((((", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // whatever you want
    }
};

// ...

row.setOnClickListener(listener);
row1.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

   ViewGroup group;

   private MyOnClickListener(ViewGroup group) {
       this.group = group;
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       int row_id = group.indexOfChild(row1); // or whatever
       Log.e("TAG", "ID: "+row_id);
   }
}
```

////////

```
MyOnClickListener listener = new MyOnClickListener(t1);
row.setOnClickListener(listener);
...

MyOnClickListener listener = new MyOnClickListener(t2);
anotherRow.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: but on click -1 id is coming n on every click it is tracking both id's for t1 and t2 -1.

Answer (score 0):

two choices:
Let your class implement `OnClickListener` and implement it inside like this:

```
class Custom implements OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case ROW1_ID:
            ....
            break;
        case ROW2_ID:
            ....
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

using it like this:

```
row1.setOnClickListener(this)
row.setOnClickListener(this)
```

or use a simple Variable like this:

```
private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case ROW1_ID:
            ....
            break;
        case ROW2_ID:
            ....
            break;
        }
}
```

using it like this:

```
row1.setOnClickListener(myListener);
row.setOnClickListener(this)
```